# why after subtraction is an extra space generated in a batch script?

Tags: script, batch-file

I am trying to copy my dbf file into a backup folder every Monday.

If the Monday is not greater then 7 then it will copy previous month file.

When I subtract 1 from the month it adds an extra space.

```
cls
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set WD=%%i
set D=%%j
set M=%%k
set Y=%%l
) 

set day="SUN"
set now="%WD%"
set /a ss=%M%-1

set j=0%ss%

IF /I "%now%"=="%day%"  ( 
    set month=%M%
) ELSE ( 
    IF %D% LEQ 7 ( 
        set month=%j% 
    ) ELSE (
            set month=%M% 
        )
    )

echo S2?%month%160.dbf
```

Current output:

```
S2?03 160.dbf
```

Desired output:

```
S2?03160.dbf
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: i found answer ,while month=%J% I used month=%J:~-2%

Comment: Put your solution as an answer and accept it... You've answered your own question :)

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the end of each line in your text editor, you will find that you have two SET statements with an unwanted trailing space at the end. You can solve the problem by removing the unwanted space.

A good practice to use when using SET is to enclose the entire assignment within quotes. All text after the final quote will be ignored, so you don't have to worry about inadvertent trailing spaces:

```
set "var=value"  This text after the last quote is ignored
```